# How can i join 2 sharepoint 2010 list

Tags: sharepoint-2010

When using SP 2007 and needed to do a join i just write the tables to a sql table and then use sql to join the tables.
What i really need to do is quite simple. 
I have a master list and another list that users insert records too lets say a child list.
When a user opens up the master list and clicks on an item i insert a record including their usernames to the child list
All i want to show the users(based on login names) is the items they haven't read and what items.
In sql i could have done something like e.g

```
 Select * from master where not in(select from child where username ='blalal')
```

Any ideas.Not sure if to do it on the client or in the object model.
Sure CAMl doesn't have joins

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can do joins in CAML queries as long as the two lists are related by a lookup field.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee539975.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the Camelot .NET Connector from Bendsoft to JOIN any fields. It supports typical CRUD commands, including LEFT and INNER joins and UNION.

Answer (score 0):

Check this approach very easy to join as many list as you want: [Link](http://cawl4sharepoint.com/cawl4sharepoint/cawl_querybuilder/)

```
cawl_QueryBuilder cawl = new cawl_QueryBuilder();
cawl.Select("Users_Title");
cawl.Select("Users_Age");
cawl.Select("Users_Sex");
cawl.Select("CarBrand");
cawl.Join("UsersList";"OwnerColumn");
cawl.Get('UserCarsList');

StringBuilder Result = new StringBuilder();
foreach (SPListItem item in cawl.ListItemCollection())
{
  Result.Append(item["Users_Title"].ToString() +
                 item["Users_Age"].ToString() +
                 item["Users_Sex"].ToString() +
                 item["CarBrand"].ToString());

}
Label1.Text = Result .ToString();
```